# Tensorflow error when using tf.keras.optimizers.SGD

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm new in tensorflow and neuronal networks, I'm trying to create a simple neural network but when I use the function tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(1).minimize to try to minimize the cost, it generates the following error

> ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['Variable:0', 'Variable:0', 'Variable:0', 'Variable:0'].

my code is the next and I'm using tensorflow 2

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x  = [[0.,0.],[1.,1.],[1.,0.],[0.,1.]]
y_ = [[0.],[0.],[1.],[1.]]

# capa 0 = the 1x2 inputs
x0 = tf.constant( x  , dtype=tf.float32 )
y0 = tf.constant( y_ , dtype=tf.float32 )

# capa 1 = the 2x3 hidden sigmoid
m1 = tf.Variable( tf.random.uniform( [2,3] , minval=0.1 , maxval=0.9 , dtype=tf.float32  )) 
b1 = tf.Variable( tf.random.uniform( [3]   , minval=0.1 , maxval=0.9 , dtype=tf.float32  )) 
h1 = tf.sigmoid( tf.matmul( x0,m1 ) + b1 ) 

# capa3 2 = the 3x1 sigmoid output
m2 = tf.Variable( tf.random.uniform( [3,1] , minval=0.1 , maxval=0.9 , dtype=tf.float32  ))
b2 = tf.Variable( tf.random.uniform( [1]   , minval=0.1 , maxval=0.9 , dtype=tf.float32  ))
y_out = tf.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul( h1,m2 ) ,b2) )

loss=lambda: tf.reduce_sum( tf.square( y0 - y_out ) )
# training step : gradient decent (1.0) to minimize loss
train = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(1.0).minimize(loss,var_list=[m1,b1,m2,b2]) #Here it generates error

### training
# run 500 times using all the X and Y
# print out the loss and any other interesting info
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run( tf.global_variables_initializer() )
  for step in range(500):
    sess.run(train)

  results = sess.run([m1,b1,m2,b2,y_out,loss])
  labels  = "m1,b1,m2,b2,y_out,loss".split(",")
  for label,result in zip(*(labels,results)) :
    print("")
    print(label)
    print(result)
    
print("")
```

Comment: try this 
train = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1.0.minimize(loss,var_list=[m1,b1,m2,b2]) #Here it generates error

Comment: This is TF 1 code. Either use TF 1.x or use code that is written with TF 2 in mind.